# Implementing Dependency Inversion & Dependency Injection both together by defining structure

Tags: dependency-injection, dependencies, nested-loops, solid

I have subcategories defined under Vehicle Class as :-
Bike
Car
truck
bus

Further, there are different variants under each four categories

1. Bike :- sport, standard
2. Car :- sport, standard, electric
   3.Truck :- Mini Truck , Power Truck
3. Bus:- Mini Bus, AC Bus

We have to calculate the price of each variants defined in each category.

Example 1 : With Constructor overloading

```
 public interface ivehicle
    {
        public void calculateprice();
    }

    public class calculatprice : ivehicle
    {
        public void calculateprice() { 
        
        }
    }

    public class bike_1
    {
        public readonly ivehicle vehicle;
        public bike_1(string model) {
            if (model == "STANDARD")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("THe price of standard is 1 lac");
            }
            else if (model == "SPORTS")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The price of sports is 2 lacs");
            }
        
        }
    }
```

Example 2:- With using overiding function and inheritance

```
    public class vehicle_3
    {
       
    }

    public class bike_3: vehicle_3
    
    {
        public virtual void Calculateprice_3() { }

    }

    public class sports_3 :bike_3
    {

        public override void Calculateprice_3()
        {
            base.Calculateprice_3();
            Console.WriteLine("The price of Sports is 2 lacs");
        }

    }

    public class standard_3 : bike_3
    {
        public override void Calculateprice_3()
        {
            base.Calculateprice_3();
            Console.WriteLine("The price of standard is 1 lacs");
        }
    }
```

Example 3:- With interface

```
    public class vehicle_4
    {

    }

    public interface ivehicle_4
    {
        void CalculatePrice_4();
    }

    public class bike_4 :ivehicle_4

    {
        public virtual void CalculatePrice_4() { }

    }
    public class sports_4 : bike_4
    {

        public override void CalculatePrice_4()
        {
            base.CalculatePrice_4();
            Console.WriteLine("The price of Sports is 2 lacs");
        }

    }

    public class standard_4 : bike_4
    {
        public override void CalculatePrice_4()
        {
            base.CalculatePrice_4();
            Console.WriteLine("The price of standard is 1 lacs");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please limit to one example, and provide some details on what is going wrong (the output).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @ryanwebjackson , I have following statement
a.  I have Bike, Car, truck, bus (4 entities) as vehicle . 
b. Then I have following categories defined under each category :
Bike :- sport, standard
Car :- sport, standard, electric 
Truck :- Mini Truck , Power Truck
Bus:- Mini Bus, AC Bus

Problem Statement : I have to calculate the price of Sports Bike, standard bike by implementing dependency injection and dependency inversion principle.

Solution:- What should be the best possible structure

Comment: That's not a good format for a StackOverflow question, because it is largely opinion based. I will say that in class-based OOP, analyze the "x is a y" relationships to determine what should inherit from what. Interfaces are a formal abstraction are for how you want to interact with class instances, and abstract classes are for hierarchy shared, generic functionality. There is a lot of information on the Web and in books about this.